# Is it possible to use the LaTeX packages "subfiles" and "background"?

Tags: packages, backgrounds, include

I ran into a problem using the packages "subfiles" and "background" in my LaTeX project.

I have a main file that looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pages=some, angle=0, opacity=1, scale=1]{background}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{204, 68, 68}

\begin{document}
    \subfile{subfile1}
    \newpage
    \subfile{subfile2}
\end{document}
```

I want to include two subfiles. The first subfile looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \backgroundsetup{
        contents={
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
                \path [fill=background] (-.5\paperwidth, 6) rectangle (.5\paperwidth, 9.25);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
    \BgThispage
    Text...
\end{document}
```

The second subfile looks similar but has a different background setting:

```latex
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    \backgroundsetup{
        contents={
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
                \path [fill=background] (-.5\paperwidth, -12.5) rectangle (.5\paperwidth, 12.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
    \BgThispage
    Text...
\end{document}
```

Compiling the two subfiles as standalone files gives me the expected result. But compiling the main file does not set the backgrounds right, even the file compiles without errors.

I figured out that the watermark appears if the included subfile is just one page long. If the content is at least two pages long the background is displayed correctly. Does anyone know why?

Is it possible to fix this error or are there working alternatives for the packages "subfiles" or "background" that work together?

Comment: Try to move the \newpage inside the first subfile (untested ...)

Comment: But then if I compile the first subfile standalone, there will be a blank page at the end.

Comment: A \newpage at the end shouldn't do anything.

Comment: I see my mistake with the \newpage-command at the end of the code. This solution works. But why didn't it work the way I did it before, can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main file deleted the \newpage command and in every subfile end the code with a \newpage command. This way the compilation of the main file and of all subfiles as standalone files works correctly.

Thanks to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) and her [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598486/is-it-possible-to-use-the-latex-packages-subfiles-and-background#comment1500417_598486).